# Rest Authentication for woocommerce oauth

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

we are using the woocommerce Rest API. If there any ways to get client key and secret key in api response for oauth authentication. We referred the below link **https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#rest-api-keys**

```
$store_url = 'http://example.com';
$endpoint = '/wc-auth/v1/authorize';
$params = [
    'app_name' => 'My App Name',
    'scope' => 'write',
    'user_id' => 123,
    'return_url' => 'http://app.com',
    'callback_url' => 'https://app.com'
];
$query_string = http_build_query( $params );

echo $store_url . $endpoint . '?' . $query_string;
```

But it Doesn't return any response. It only returns the post values only send by me.